How to dynamically pass key and get value in an iterator in LWC html
How do i iterate the second iterator object in html using the key from the first iterator. Key in second iterator = First iterator record.Question.value
Appreciate the help..
Console log statements:
First iterator: 3 rows
titleMap
[
  {
    "Name": "Oil Gas Salt Resources Act 1990",
    "Id": "a1S05000006zh5CEAQ",
    "Question": "a1b05000005DzfzAAC"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Ontario Regulation 245/97",
    "Id": "a1S05000006zh5JEAQ",
    "Question": "a1b05000005DzgOAAS"
  },
  {
    "Name": "OGSRA Provincial Operating Standards",
    "Id": "a1S05000006zh5SEAQ",
    "Question": "a1b05000005Dzf2AAC"
  }
]


Second iterator: Key in second iterator object is the "Question" value from the first iterator
sectionMap
{
  "a1b05000005DzfzAAC": [
    {
      "Name": "4(1) Obstruction of inspector",
      "Question": "a1b05000005Dzg4AAC",
      "Id": "a1S05000006zh5DEAQ"
    },
    {
      "Name": "4(3) Refusal to produce records or make examinations",
      "Question": "a1b05000005Dzg0AAC",
      "Id": "a1S05000006zh5FEAQ"
    }
  ],
  "a1b05000005DzgOAAS": [
    {
      "Name": "7 Registration of Works",
      "Question": "a1b05000005Dzg5AAC",
      "Id": "a1S05000006zh5KEAQ"
    }
  ],
  "a1b05000005Dzf2AAC": [
    {
      "Name": "2. Injection Permits",
      "Question": "a1b05000005DzgPAAS",
      "Id": "a1S05000006zh5TEAQ"
    }
  ]
}

JS code:
        data.forEach(row => {
            if(row.Question_Type__c == 'Title'){
                let titleRec = {};
                titleRec.Name = row.BGCK__Page_Question__r.BGCK__Question__r.BGCK__Body__c;                        
                titleRec.Id = row.Id;
                titleRec.Question = row.BGCK__Page_Question__r.BGCK__Question__c;
                this.titleMap.push(titleRec);                        
            }

            if(row.Question_Type__c == 'Section'){
                let secRec = {};         
                secRec.Name = row.BGCK__Page_Question__r.BGCK__Question__r.BGCK__Body__c;
                secRec.Question = row.BGCK__Page_Question__r.BGCK__Question__c;               
                secRec.Id = row.Id;
                this.addValueToKey(row.BGCK__Page_Question__r.BGCK__Question__r.MNRF_Title_Question_Id__c , secRec);
            }
        });
addValueToKey(key, value) {
    this.sectionMap[key] = this.sectionMap[key] || [];
    // Adds a value to the end of the Array
    this.sectionMap[key].push(value);
}

HTML Code:
    <lightning-card title="Checklist Questions New">
        <lightning-accordion active-section-name="title">
            <template for:each={titleMap} for:item="titleRec">
                    <lightning-accordion-section name="title" label={titleRec.Name} key={titleRec.Id}>
                        <template for:each={sectionMap[titleRec.Question]} for:item="secRec">
                                {secRec}
                                <lightning-accordion-section name="sec" label={secRec.Name} key={secRec.Id}>
                                        Section data
                                </lightning-accordion-section> 
                        </template>
                    </lightning-accordion-section>
            </template> 
        </lightning-accordion>
    </lightning-card> 


Unlike Visualforce and some other languages, you can't dynamically choose a field from an object/map in LWC. It's just not supported. Instead, you'll need to create a structure where you have an object with a property that is an array, and each element in the array will contain a property that is itself an array.
this.titles = this.titleMap.map((titleObject) => ({
  ...titleObject,
  Sections: this.sectionMap[titleObject.Question],
}));

Which then changes your template to:
<lightning-card title="Checklist Questions New">
    <lightning-accordion active-section-name="title">
        <template for:each={titles} for:item="title">
                <lightning-accordion-section name="title" label={title.Name} key={title.Id}>
                    <template for:each={title.Sections} for:item="section">
                        <lightning-accordion-section name={!section.Name} label={section.Name} key={section.Id}>
                                Section data
                        </lightning-accordion-section> 
                    </template>
                </lightning-accordion-section>
        </template> 
    </lightning-accordion>
</lightning-card> 


Hi sfdcfox - Thank you so much for your response. Appreciate it. It WORKED!!

I further expanded the code and final map looked like below: As i could not paste the complete data, I am pasting the data of relevance:
{"Name":"OGSRA Provincial Operating
"Sections":[{"Name":"2. Injection
"SubSections":[{"Name":"2.3 Injection well/project construction, operation & "}]
}
Sections has nested property SubSections, which prints the value in JS. However when i display it n html it is not showing when I expand the accordion

Here is the html part:



@user5352 You can edit your question or (preferably) ask a new question with the latest problem, and we'll be happy to help.

Thank you . I will post as a new question
